# How to attach bargraph bars to bottom without fixed height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a bar graph to show visitor stats, but I cannot figure out how to attach the bars to the bottom without knowing the exact height. I do the height in % and it's different basically every time you check so I cannot set a fixed height.

My code is:

CSS:

```
#graph {
    width: 447px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
    background-image:url(css/bargraph.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    position: relative;
}

#graphtext {
    padding-left:17px;
    width: 430px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    font-size:9px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}

.bartext {
    width: 10%;
    margin-right: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:5px;
}

#bar {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:17px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,240,84) 0%, rgb(0,187,255) 68%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,240,84) 0%, rgb(0,187,255) 68%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,240,84) 0%, rgb(0,187,255) 68%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,240,84) 0%, rgb(0,187,255) 68%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,240,84) 0%, rgb(0,187,255) 68%);
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    position:absolute !important;
    bottom:0px !important;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="graph">
<div style="height:250px; width:447px; position:absolute;">
            <div style="height: 29%;" id="bar" title="43234 Visitors, 3024 Unique Visitors"></div><!--
         --><div style="height: 11%;" id="bar" title="43234 Visitors, 3024 Unique Visitors"></div><!--
         --><div style="height: 6%;" id="bar" title="43234 Visitors, 3024 Unique Visitors"></div><!--
         --><div style="height: 49%;" id="bar" title="43234 Visitors, 3024 Unique Visitors"></div><!--
         --><div style="height: 59%;" id="bar" title="43234 Visitors, 3024 Unique Visitors"></div><!--
         --><div style="height: 2%;" id="bar" title="43234 Visitors, 3024 Unique Visitors"></div><!--
         --><div style="height: 40%;" id="bar" title="43234 Visitors, 3024 Unique Visitors"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="graphtext">
        <div class="bartext">Monday</div><!--
        --><div class="bartext">Tuesday</div><!--
        --><div class="bartext">Wednesday</div><!--
        --><div class="bartext">Thursday</div><!--
        --><div class="bartext">Friday</div><!--
        --><div class="bartext">Saturday</div><!--
        --><div class="bartext">Sunday</div>
</div>
```

Which yields:

[image: With absolute position]

And removing the absolute position yields:
[image: without absolute position]

Any clues?

Comment: An `id` should be unique, use a `class` instead (for `#bar`)

Comment: @F4r-20 Didn't work :( Still the same as example #2

Comment: That wasn't an answer.. I'm just saying: don't use duplicate ids

Comment: @F4r-20 Oh :P well okay

Comment: If you position an element absolutely and don't set `left` or `right`, it defaults to `left: 0` causing all of your bars to be on the left.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Alright, but i have margin-right:17px; to fix the space between the bars, but with absolute ignores margin-right, any idea how i would go about fixing that?

Answer (score 2):

If you position an element absolutely and don't set left or right, it defaults to left: 0 causing all of your bars to be on the left.

You can remove the absolute positioning and simply add `vertical-align: bottom` to the boxes and set the `line-height` of the parent div equal to its height:

```
<div style="height:250px;line-height: 250px; width:447px; position:absolute; ">
```

```
#bar {
    /* ... */

    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NLf6j/

As noted in the comments though, `id` values should always be unique.  You should change this to a class.

Comment: Great solution. I wanted to suggest doing this with js like this: http://jsfiddle.net/urPa6/1/ but your solution is much better.

Comment: Looks great in the jsfiddle but for some reason when i change and add the new changes or even copy+paste your code it still doesn't attach to the bottom, i'll see if i can figure out whats causing it.

Answer (score 0):

A sort of dumb solution, but perhaps one that you could work with: http://jsfiddle.net/ajhf7/2/

I've called the div around the bars the `#graph-container`, and given it these properties:

```
#graph-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -41%;
}
```

The 41% is calculated by subtracting the tallest bar (59%) from 100%.

The solution posted earlier with `vertical-align: bottom` is obviously much cleaner and doesn't require any calculations, but if for some reason that doesn't work for you, here's an alternative.

(Note that I also removed `position: relative` and some other stuff from the `.bar` elements, and changed it from `#bar` to `.bar` because of the no-duplicate-ids rule.)